# Can The Wolverine be viewed as a stand-alone film?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

I really want to watch this movie *The Wolverine*, and was wondering if I have to watch something before watching this movie so that I won't miss or not get part of the movie?

Which of the previous *X-Men* films are required viewing before watching *The Wolverine*?

Comment: Straight answer......no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The film depends heavily on the events of *X-Men 3: The Last Stand*.  In that film, Wolverine does something he regrets heavily, and it is the basis for his character arc in *The Wolverine*.  So to fully appreciate this film, you should watch *X-Men 3*.

But to fully appreciate *X-Men 3*, you should see *X-Men* and *X-Men 2*, since it's a sequel to those, and a continuation of those stories.

You can skip *X-Men: First Class*, as it has no bearing on *The Wolverine*.  And you should skip *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* for the many reasons critics described back when it was released (it also doesn't have much bearing on *The Wolverine*).

---

Alternatively, if you're familiar with the X-Men from the comics, and are aware of some of the key storylines that occurred there, you can read this spoiler to get up to speed:

> In *X-Men 3*, Jean Grey is taken over by the Phoenix.  She goes on a rampage, allies with Magneto and begins a mutant vs. human war.  Wolverine is forced to kill her because she's completely out of control.

Comment: This is really good answer @Keen Thanks! I have made a mistake last night by watching X-Men 3 without watching X-Men and X-Men 2, but didn't really get so confuse, but felt like something is missing which I should have watch the first two first. So, I guess I'm going to watch those first two first then will watch The Wolverine :). Thanks once again.